# Problem with cache:clear command with --no-warmup option after upgrade SF from 3.3 to 3.4

Tags: symfony, upgrade

I have a strange problem with clearing cache with `--no-warmup` flag after upgrade SF from 3.3 to 3.4 version.
The command remove all cache files which is fine but after that there is event `console.terminate` dispatched which return such error

```
Compile Error: Container8yvgvsp\appDevDebugProjectContainer::load(): Failed opening required '/var/www/project/var/cache/dev/Container8yvgvsp/getSwiftmailer_EmailSender_Listener  
  Service.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php')
```

I tried to check what is going on with event listeners and I found that they are a Closure functions which are pointing to the cache files which have been already deleted :(. I tried to find the differences between 3.3 and 3.4 versions but without effect.

Also I deleted manually all cache files but problem still exist.

**Note:** Project has been upgraded from 2.8 to 3.4 version step by step. On each previous versions everything is working fine. On 3.4 also site is working ok except cache clearing without warmup which is very important for me.

Any tips :)

Thanks!

Comment: If the problem exists after manually deleting caches, i guess the problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. The problem was with one of the custom command which override `cache:clear --no-warmup` native Symfony command. Native command for clear cache has been rebuilt in 3.4 version so it can not work.